# How can I lookup the timestamp of the latest maven build of a project?

Tags: debugging, logging, build, maven

If I was building from a Terminal I'd ctrl+F `mvn install` and check the timestamp, but otherwise (building through NB) is there a file log to which builds history is written?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your the name your artifact will generate to have a timestamp appended onto it using finalName.

${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}

Other than that, you could use a CI (Continuous Integration) server like Teamcity to build the artifacts for you. Teamcity will then generate logs with timestamps.